# Best practices for adding compile sources to a Prefix.pch file

Tags: xcode

I'd like to put some categories I wrote for different projects into a central folder and put the header files together with some common macros into a mystuff.h which I'd like to add to the Prefix.pch like so:

**Prefix.pch:**

```
#import "myStuff.h"
```

**myStuff.h**

```
#import "/Users/foo/Documents/Xcode-Projects/my_stuff/NSNumber+someCategory.h"

#if DEBUG
// some macros
#endif
```

The goal is to add only the one line where I import `myStuff.h` to the `Prefix.pch` file of a new project and be done. The approach above so far compiles fine, but the runtime throws exceptions for all the category methods I use in the project, because the `.m` files of the categories don't get compiled.

So far I found two solutions:
a) I can add the `.m` files manually to "Build Phases => Compile Sources"
b) for every `.h` file that I import in `myStuff.h` I add the associated `.m` file, like so:

**myStuff.h**

```
#import "/Users/foo/Documents/Xcode-Projects/my_stuff/NSNumber+someCategory.h"
#import "/Users/foo/Documents/Xcode-Projects/my_stuff/NSNumber+someCategory.m"
```

(or merge the `.h`'s into the `.m`'s)

While approach a) seems to be clean, it does require additional work, whereas approach b) requires less work but I'm not sure whether that is best practice. Any ideas on how to solve this cleanly, or is approach b) acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to put your categories together into a library, and then refer to that library in your current project.  See Ray Wenderlich's example at:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: Thanks, that lookspretty much like what I need. Sorry can't upvote your answer because of lack of rep points :-(

Comment: So I just tried the sub-project approach from the above link, and it works fine, but the `-ObjC` flag is needed for every project. Is there a way to add this flag to a `.h` file?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is a library or framework. [Here are the docs for creating a framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html) in Xcode. Or if you want to build a library for iOS [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2812261?start=0&tstart=0) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful but a bit complicated for now. It might get useful when my library of code gets bigger though. Sorry can't upvote your answer because I'm lacking 1 rep point :-(